# Как разъединить соединение определенному клиенту socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Нужно завершить (оборвать, разъединить) соединение определенному активному клиенту.

Известен socket id.

Comment: Судя по тому, что [здесь написано](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L421), должно получиться `socket.disconnect(true);` btw лучше  храните не socket.id у клиента, а ссылку на его сокет.

Comment: Каждый пользователь при коннекте к серверу через socket.io получает свой уникальный ключ или скажем, поток. Думаю, нужно в этом направлении поискать функции.